# split object in dataframe pandas without delimiters

Tags: python, pandas, string, dataframe, split

I'm learning python and now I want to split a string without delimiters.
string is in a dataframe column pandas and I want to divide the string into multiple columns.

What is the best way?

Data:

"Naam: TEST B.V. Omschrijving: Factuur 20-01-2024, klantnummer 1234567890. IBAN: NL41INGB0000467598 Kenmerk: 000011292292967 Machtiging ID: M10024815057 Incassant ID: NL39KPN271247010001 Doorlopende incasso Valutadatum: 24-01-2024"

expect output:

| Naam | Omschrijving | IBAN | Kenmerk | MachtigingID | IncassantID | Valutadatum |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| TEST B.V. | Factuur 20-01-2024, klantnummer 1234567890 | NL41INGB0000467598 | 000011292292967 | M10024815057 | NL39KPN271247010001 | 24-01-2024 |

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: How consistent are those fields?  It seems like you asking about string manipulation also.  Have you researched options like regex?

Comment: i want string manipulation and i tried regex but i don't get it. The fields are not consistent and i want a column for each key(...:) and the value. The answer helps me alot but is not the output that i want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using a regex to extract the word before `':'` as a key (without shade except if ending in `' ID'`:

```
import re

data = "Naam: TEST B.V. Omschrijving: Factuur 20-01-2024, klantnummer 1234567890. IBAN: NL41INGB0000467598 Kenmerk: 000011292292967 Machtiging ID: M10024815057 Incassant ID: NL39KPN271247010001 Doorlopende incasso Valutadatum: 24-01-2024"

out = pd.DataFrame([dict(re.findall(r'(\S+(?: ID)?): ([^:]+?) *(?=$|\b[^:\s]+(?: ID)?:)', data))])
```

*Note that it takes the full string after `IncassantID`, you might need to post-process it if you really just need the first word.*

Output:

```
        Naam                                 Omschrijving                IBAN          Kenmerk Machtiging ID                             Incassant ID Valutadatum
0  TEST B.V.  Factuur 20-01-2024, klantnummer 1234567890.  NL41INGB0000467598  000011292292967  M10024815057  NL39KPN271247010001 Doorlopende incasso  24-01-2024
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/N26Bo5/1)

Comment: i want string manipulation and i tried regex but i don't get it. The fields are not consistent and i want a column for each key(...:) and the value. The answer helps me alot but is not the output that i want.

Comment: Then you have to provide a better example. Also keep in mind that it's unlikely to have a perfect solution that will work in all cases without supervision.

Comment: With your example i come to this regex:
r'(\bOmschrijving\b:) ([^:]+?) *(?=$|\b[^:\s]+(?: ID)?:)'
1 line for each column i want.
So Thank you for your answer!